# my script deletes user accounts that have not been logged in for more than 30 days, in fact it works, but it deletes some system accounts

Tags: bash

It works, but also deletes some system accounts...i don't know why

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script takes everyone with id>1000 from /etc/passwd and removes every user account in case if it hasn't been used for the last 30 days.

# Make sure that script is being executed with root priviligies.

if [[ "${UID}" -ne 0 ]]
then
echo "You should run this script as a root!"
exit 1
fi

# First of all we need to know id limit (min & max)

USER_MIN=$(grep "^UID_MIN" /etc/login.defs)

USER_MAX=$(grep "^UID_MAX" /etc/login.defs)

# Print all users accounts with id>=1000 and <=6000 (default).

awk -F':' -v "min=${USER_MIN##UID_MIN}" -v "max=${USER_MAX##UID_MAX}" ' { if ( $3 >= min && $3 <= max ) print $0}' /etc/passwd

# This function deletes users which hasn't log in in the last 30 days

# Make a color output message

for accounts in ` lastlog -b 30 | sed "1d" | awk ' { print $1 } '`

do

userdel $accounts 2>/dev/null

done

echo -e "\e[36mYou have successfully deleted all user's account which nobody logged in in the past 30 days.\e[0,"

exit 0
```

Comment: You're suppressing errors by doing `2>/dev/null` and `exit 0`

Comment: Your script simply deletes all users that `lastlog -b 30 | ...`  outputs.

Comment: i thought i indicated it above in the script..how i can fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash and GNU grep:

```
#!/bin/bash

# I left out the check for root user

# get only the numbers from each line
# \K removes the matching part before \K (from left to right)
USER_MIN=$(grep -Po "^UID_MIN *\K.*" /etc/login.defs)
USER_MAX=$(grep -Po "^UID_MAX *\K.*" /etc/login.defs)

# create an associative array, see: help declare
declare -A users
# read all users with its uid to this associative array
while IFS=":" read -r user x uid x; do users[$user]="$uid"; done </etc/passwd
# see output of: declare -p users

# remove all unwanted lines including headline. NR is line number
lastlog -b 30 | awk '! /Never logged in/ && NR>1 {print $1}' |
  while read -r user; do

    # -ge: greater-than-or-equal
    # -le: less-than-or-equal
    if [[ ${users[$user]} -ge $USER_MIN ]] && [[ ${users[$user]} -le $USER_MAX ]]; then
      echo "delete user $user with uid ${users[$user]}"
      # add your code here to delete user $user
    fi
  done
```

Comment: finally i get it..thank you so much for your help. really appreciate

Comment: your answear helps me to solve my test assigment..so i get a new job recently. That's just a reminder how big was your help :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help you.

Answer (score 2):

You do not apply the `awk -F':' -v "min=${USER_MIN##UID_MIN}" -v "max=${USER_MAX##UID_MAX}" ' { if ( $3 >= min && $3 <= max ) print $0}' /etc/passwd` filter to `lastlog` output....

Join the list from lastlog with the list of users from /etc/passwd and filter UID with proper number range.

```
lastlog -b30 | sed 1d | awk '{print $1}' |
sort | join -t: -11 -21 -o2.1,2.3 - <(sort /etc/passwd) |
awk -F: -v "min=${USER_MIN##UID_MIN}" -v "max=${USER_MAX##UID_MAX}" '$2 >= min && $2 <= max {print $1}' |
xargs -n1 echo userdel
```

Notes:

- Do not use backticks `. Use `$(...)` instead. [Obsolete and deprecated syntax](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete)
- [how to read a stream line by line in bash bashfaq](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: okay, with your modifications this script will delete all user's account in case it hasn't been used for 30 days ?

Comment: are you sure you didn't forget to specify userdell action ?

Comment: `his script will delete all user's` - no, the part of the script as it is, will execute `echo userdel <the_user>` foreach username. `are you sure` Yes, I am sure. I  used `xargs` to execute `echo userdel` for each user. Remove the `echo` to really remove the user. Use `-t` with `xargs` for debugging. Iterating over input with `for i in command` is an anti-pattern, use a `while read` loop. Read the second note I posted in the answer.

Comment: i really appreciate your help, but i'm so confused about all this scripting at the end of the working day..can you please edit my example according to my requirements and send to me ? i'll be very greatful